# Passing JS variable name to function

Tags: javascript, json, variables

So here is what I am trying to do:

1. My variable named `data_1` is set.

   ```
   var data_1 = {
     "y_legend": {
       "text": "# of Patients",
       "style": "{font-size: 20px; color: #778877}"
     },
     "x_legend": {
       "text": "AUG 09 - OCT 09",
       "style": "{font-size: 20px; color: #778877}"
     }
   };
   ```
2. In a drop down a user selects an option with the value of `data_1` that calls `load('data_1')`.

   ```
   function load(data)
   {
     tmp = findSWF("my_chart");
     x = tmp.load( JSON.stringify(data) );
   }
   ```

My Problem: I'm selecting an option with the value `data_1` and not the variable itself.
So in my function `load('data_1')`, when I `alert(data)` I get `data = 'data_1'`.

So how do I get the contents of my variable `data_1` in my load function by passing only the name of the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data_1 = { /* data goes here */ };

var data_choices = {1: data_1, 2: data_2, /* and so on */};

var load = function (data) {
    // data is "1", "2", etc. If you want to use the full data_1 name, change
    // the data_choices object keys.

    var tmp = findSWF("my_chart");
    var x = tmp.load( JSON.stringify(data_choices[data]) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! I will have to try window out above also.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a global variable, you can reference it with

```
window['the_variable_name']
```

E.g.

```
function load(data)
{ 
  tmp = findSWF( "my_chart" ); 
  x = tmp.load( JSON.stringify( window[data] ) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

or you could simply use

```
alert(eval(data))
```

Comment: Whoah! You have to be REALLY CAREFUL when using eval()! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: as stated in the second answer in the post u linked : eval isn't always evil. There are times where it's perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @Matt Ball  Not agree to give -1 to this answer because suggest to use Eval. Eval could be use carrefully, but could be practice to be use for debug.